# having problems when inserting 6 marks in 6 school subjects

Tags: php, mysql

I try to insert 6 marks in 6 subject for one student .I have 3 tables (students,subjects,marks) the problem is that only the last mark is inserted in all subject

Comment: Please. No images.

Comment: SO allows you to paste the code in your question.

Comment: Honestly; you post an image of code. -1 for this question.

Comment: not to mention a nice sql injection

Comment: Voted to close as unclear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All of your `name`'s for `inputs` are the same, so it only can see one of them, it doesn't know the difference between `"mark"` and `"mark"` and `"mark"` etc. Add different id's to them, like "`mark1`" etc.

Then in your php, MAKE SURE TO SANITISE THE INPUTS!! or else people can use sql injection to echo out absolutely everything including the schema of all your databases.

Check the inputs using their names, like `$mark1 = $_POST['mark1'];` Again, sanitise $mark1 even if it is only you using it locally. It's good practice (:

EDIT:

Problems:
*In your SQL Query, you never use the php variable $mark, because you add "$mark" as a string to the database.

*You don't sanitise any of the user input, so this db is vulnerable to attack

*Your HTML Inputs in the form all have the same name "mark" so the php doesn't know the different data inside each one, because they are all called the same.

Steps to resolve this:

*Give your `HTML` Inputs unique `name attributes`.

*In your `PHP`, get those unique `name attributes` as `unique variables`.

*Change your `Query` from `'$mark'` to `'" . $mark1 . "',` etc.

*Sanitise your inputs, there are plenty of topics on SO to learn this.

Comment: I have used mark as a column name for tha marks table

Comment: @ema Yes, but if I said to you, what is the value of "mark", you wont know which "mark" input I am talking about, the php assumes the last input in the list is "mark" because it overwrites all the others before it. You need to give inputs unique names or else the php has as much of a clue as anyone...

Comment: THANK YOUUUU JASOM YOU SAVED MY DAY

Comment: So someone marked this down? Why?